# Delta live tables problem - The column name(s) 'Alpha Source' , 'Alpha source' are duplicated in dataset

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

I am trying to load csv files from Datalake into delta tables but I am getting duplicate column name issue while spinning up the tables.

My CSV looks something like this -

```
Id  Alpha Source    Alpha source
1   AKH              null
2   AKG
```

And I trying to load the table from abfss -

```
@dlt.table(comment="load csv files in bronze",
       name = "dev.bronze.logs",
       table_properties = {
           'delta.columnMapping.mode': 'name'
       })
def table():
 landing_zone_path = "abfss://landing@sadatalake.dfs.core.windows.net/log/"
 df = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles") \
    .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv") \
    .option("header","true")\
    .option("inferSchema", "True")\
    .load(landing_zone_path)
 return df
```

Instead it fails -
[image]

I would expect the additional columns to go into _rescue_data but thats not happening. I also tried using **spark.conf.set('spark.sql.caseSensitive', True)** but that dint work too.

Comment: The `spark.sql.caseSensitive` configuration is used to make Spark SQL case-sensitive, which means it will distinguish between uppercase and lowercase when interpreting each column name. However, it is not used for handling duplicate column names.